# Get the maximum pixel width of the browser in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows

I have a 1920x1080 monitor. My Windows GUI scaling is sized to 125%. That means that for a website to look like normal 100% scaling, I need to zoom Chrome to 80% (80% * 125% = 1). (So in this case, devicePixelRatio is 1.)

I would like to get the maximum size in pixels of the browser window -- that is, what the size would be if it was maximized.

One would think `window.screen.width` would do it, but in Chrome, I get 1536, not 1920. (1536 is 1920 / 1.25)

I've come up with three solutions: one for Chrome, one for Edge, and one for Firefox. The only thing I'm trying to figure out now is how to synchronize the solutions into one:

Chrome:

```
let adj = (window.screen.width == window.outerWidth) ? 0 : -15
let maxScreenWidth = document.body.getBoundingClientRect().width * (window.screen.width / (window.outerWidth + adj))
```

Edge:

```
// Edit: simply "window.screen.width" also works here.
let adj = (window.screen.width == window.outerWidth) ? 0 : -18
let maxScreenWidth = document.body.getBoundingClientRect().width * (window.screen.width / (window.outerWidth + adj))
```

Firefox: (!)

```
let maxScreenWidth = window.screen.width
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is my solution. Waiting on a bug report response, but meanwhile:

```
var adj = (window.screen.width == window.outerWidth) ? 0 : -15
var maxScreenWidth = window.innerWidth * (window.screen.width / (window.outerWidth + adj))
if (parseInt(maxScreenWidth) != maxScreenWidth) maxScreenWidth = window.screen.width
```

Answer (score 0):

If your individual solutions work for each browser you mention, you could just try to detect the browser from the user agent string and apply the correct technique on that condition. Of course, users can change their user agent strings, but it might work for your purposes.

```
let isChrome = !!window.chrome && (!!window.chrome.webstore || !!window.chrome.runtime);
let isEdge = !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia;
let isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== "undefined";
let isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;
let isSafari = /constructor/i.test(window.HTMLElement) || (function (p) { return p.toString() === "[object SafariRemoteNotification]"; })(!window['safari'] || (typeof safari !== 'undefined' && safari.pushNotification));

if (isChrome) {
    let adj = (window.screen.width == window.outerWidth) ? 0 : -15;
    let maxScreenWidth = document.body.getBoundingClientRect().width * (window.screen.width / (window.outerWidth + adj));
} else if (isIE || isEdge) {
    let adj = (window.screen.width == window.outerWidth) ? 0 : -18
    let maxScreenWidth = document.body.getBoundingClientRect().width * (window.screen.width / (window.outerWidth + adj));
} else if (isFirefox) {
    let maxScreenWidth = window.screen.width;
} else {
    // Some default
}
```

Or wrap this into a function that you can call and just return the `maxScreenWidth` from it.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I figured out Edge also gives the right solution with window.screen.width. I don't think I can use browser detection because it seems quite possible this is a bug in Chrome (or it could be a feature?).